# removeChildByTag: child not found error

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

removeChildByTag: child not found Here is my code, please help!
I am a fairly new developer with cocos2d so i can't work out what is causing Xcode to give me this error.

```
//Life System
        CCSprite *Life3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
        Life3.position = ccp(210,200);
        CCSprite *Life2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
        Life2.position = ccp(220,200);
        CCSprite *Life1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
        Life1.position = ccp(230,200);
        [self addChild:Life3];
        [self addChild:Life2];
        [self addChild:Life1];
        if(Life == 2) {
            [self removeChildByTag:Life3];
        }
        else if(Life == 1) {
            [self removeChild:Life2];
            [self removeChild:Life3];
        }
        else if(Life <= 0) {
            [self removeChild:Life1];
            [self removeChild:Life2];
            [self removeChild:Life3];
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[MainMenu scene]]];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the conditional for Life == 2, it should be removeChild, not removeChildByTag

Comment: In what way? Is there a different error, same one? If it's the same error, search your project for removeChildByTag and ensure you mean it and not just removeChild

Answer (score 0):

I have posted your code with the proper way to remove child by tag.
`removeChildByTag` needs an integer tag, and not an object (in your case, a sprite)

```
    CCSprite *Life3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
    Life3.tag = 3;
    Life3.position = ccp(210,200);

    CCSprite *Life2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
    Life2.tag = 2;
    Life2.position = ccp(220,200);

    CCSprite *Life1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
    Life1.tag = 1;
    Life1.position = ccp(230,200);

    [self addChild:Life3];
    [self addChild:Life2];
    [self addChild:Life1];

    if(Life == 2) {
        [self removeChildByTag:3];
    }
    else if(Life == 1) {
        [self removeChild:2];
        [self removeChild:1];
    }
    else if(Life <= 0) {
        [self removeChild:1];
        [self removeChild:2];
        [self removeChild:3];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[MainMenu scene]]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all [self removeChild:] or [self removeChildbyTag:] with

[self removeChild:Life1 cleanup:YES]

If this also doesn't work, I suggest you just [self addChild:] when you need to. Don't add all three Lifes as children at the beginning. So the code would become:

```
CCSprite *Life3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
    Life3.position = ccp(210,200);
    CCSprite *Life2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
    Life2.position = ccp(220,200);
    CCSprite *Life1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
    Life1.position = ccp(230,200);

    if(Life == 2) {
        [self addChild:Life2];
        [self addChild:Life1];
    }
    else if(Life == 1) {
        [self addChild:Life1];
    }
    else if(Life <= 0) {
       [self addChild:Life3];
       [self addChild:Life2];
       [self addChild:Life1];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[MainMenu scene]]];
    }
```